# Why forwarding return value is needed

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, perfect-forwarding

In the [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) of `std::forward`, it gave the following example:

```
template<class T>
void wrapper(T&& arg)
{
    foo(forward<decltype(forward<T>(arg).get())>(forward<T>(arg).get()));
}
```

Why is forwarding of return value needed here? What's the cases where it is different to the following code:

```
template<class T>
void wrapper(T&& arg)
{
    foo(forward<T>(arg).get());
}
```

Comment: See the motivaating example just below the line you have mentioned in the https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward . It refers to cases where  the underlying get() function has 2 implementations. One where you can modify the member value: `int & get() & {return i;}` and the other one where you can not `int get() && {return i;}`

Comment: @indeterminatelysequenced I still don't get it. Wouldn't the type of `forward<T>(arg).get()` the same as the argument of `forward<decltype(forward<T>(arg).get())>`, so why is the `forward` needed here?

Comment: That's the same confusion I have. The expression `forward<T>(arg).get()` is already in the correct value category so I would say there is no need to forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's break down the possibilities. `T::get` could return an lvalue reference (which is an lvalue expression), an rvalue reference (which is an xvalue expression), or a prvalue.

The `forward` expression will convert the lvalue expression into... an lvalue expression. It will convert the xvalue into... an xvalue. And it will convert a prvalue into an xvalue.

C++'s rules about how arguments bind to parameters in overload resolution are *the same* for prvalue and xvalue expressions. So the last two will always call the same function.

Therefore, the outer `forward` accomplishes nothing. Indeed, it is *worse* than doing nothing at all. Why?

Because prvalues in C++17 and above have guaranteed elision; xvalues *do not*. If `foo` takes the parameter by value, the additional `forward` will manifest an unnecessary temporary, which will then be moved into the argument. If the type is something more complex than an `int`, then there's a decent chance that you're going to lose some performance.

So don't forward return values which you are going to pass directly as function arguments. If you need to store the value in an intermediary `auto&&` variable, then you'll need to forward that. But if you're doing it in-situ like this, don't.

Comment: Yep, the example is an anti-pattern

Answer (score 4):

[The edit it was added in](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp%2Futility%2Fforward&diff=88391&oldid=88121) claims it is an example for the second overload:

```
template< class T >
constexpr T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t ) noexcept;
```

The example is not very good, as is already an rvalue. Actually I don't think the second overload is all that useful, except for making:

```
std::forward<decltype(expression)>(expression);
```

work for all expressions (Including if `expression` is an rvalue), but most use cases for `std::forward` are limited to the lvalues of `T&&` and `auto&&`.