# Is forwarding an rvalue as an rvalue a use case?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, perfect-forwarding, template-argument-deduction

I am wondering about forwarding:
The standard implements `std::forward` basically with two overloads:

1. To forward **lvalues** as **lvalues/rvalues** (dep. of `T`)

```cpp
template<typename T>
T&& forward(lvalue_Reference v){ 
    return static_cast<T&&>(v); 
};
```

2. To forward **rvalues** as **rvalues**

```cpp
template<typename T>
T&& forward(rvalue_Reference v){  
    // static-assert: T is not an lvalue-Reference
    return static_cast<T&&>(v); 
};
```

First case comes to play when

```cpp
template<typename T>
void foo(T&& a) { doSomething(std::forward<T>(a)); /* a is lvalue -> matches 1. overload */ }
```

The second case makes sense, but what is an example of triggering it?

Comment: Well, totally depends on the use case :-P ...

Comment: The second case is a universal reference and it forwards both: lvalues as lvalues, rvalues as rvalues.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: The second argument is actually: `rvalue_Reference := typename std::remove_reference_t<T>&&` and is not a forwarding-reference (universal reference) as far as I know... so your statement is incorrect.

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56416819/why-forwarding-return-value-is-needed/56417076#56417076) (Similar question, but I wrote an answer that answers this question too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a duplicate of:

[What is the purpose of std::forward()'s rvalue reference overload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56361755/what-is-the-purpose-of-stdforwards-rvalue-reference-overload)

Please also read the included paper:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html